# Rails 6 routing failed in production without log entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, production

I deploy my first rails app and my problem is, that the landingpage is perfect loading with status code 200 in my production.log

```
I, [2020-05-20T10:47:33.715546 #9931]  INFO -- : [cdcf800e-caaf-4ffe-9d88-646e84d91e2a] Started GET "/" for 79.241.182.157 at 2020-05-20 10:47:33 +0200
I, [2020-05-20T10:47:33.716706 #9931]  INFO -- : [cdcf800e-caaf-4ffe-9d88-646e84d91e2a] Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
I, [2020-05-20T10:47:33.718426 #9931]  INFO -- : [cdcf800e-caaf-4ffe-9d88-646e84d91e2a]   Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
I, [2020-05-20T10:47:33.719259 #9931]  INFO -- : [cdcf800e-caaf-4ffe-9d88-646e84d91e2a]   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 169)
I, [2020-05-20T10:47:33.723963 #9931]  INFO -- : [cdcf800e-caaf-4ffe-9d88-646e84d91e2a]   Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 164)
I, [2020-05-20T10:47:33.724139 #9931]  INFO -- : [cdcf800e-caaf-4ffe-9d88-646e84d91e2a]   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (Duration: 0.9ms | Allocations: 221)
I, [2020-05-20T10:47:33.724409 #9931]  INFO -- : [cdcf800e-caaf-4ffe-9d88-646e84d91e2a]   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 5)
I, [2020-05-20T10:47:33.724788 #9931]  INFO -- : [cdcf800e-caaf-4ffe-9d88-646e84d91e2a] Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 6.7ms | Allocations: 1217)
```

but if I route to another page, I get a 404 error without a new entry in production.log

My routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :emails

  root 'pages#home'
  get 'unserStall', to: 'pages#our_stall'
  get 'galerie', to: 'pages#gallery'
  get 'kontakt', to: 'pages#contact'
  get 'emails/new', to: 'pages#contact'
  get 'notifications', to: 'pages#notifications'
  post 'kontakt', to: 'emails#create'
end
```

Wenn I run

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails routes
```

I get this output:

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                               emails GET    /emails(.:format)                                                                        emails#index
                                      POST   /emails(.:format)                                                                        emails#create
                            new_email GET    /emails/new(.:format)                                                                    emails#new
                           edit_email GET    /emails/:id/edit(.:format)                                                               emails#edit
                                email GET    /emails/:id(.:format)                                                                    emails#show
                                      PATCH  /emails/:id(.:format)                                                                    emails#update
                                      PUT    /emails/:id(.:format)                                                                    emails#update
                                      DELETE /emails/:id(.:format)                                                                    emails#destroy
                                 root GET    /                                                                                        pages#home
                           unserStall GET    /unserStall(.:format)                                                                    pages#our_stall
                              galerie GET    /galerie(.:format)                                                                       pages#gallery
                              kontakt GET    /kontakt(.:format)                                                                       pages#contact
                           emails_new GET    /emails/new(.:format)                                                                    pages#contact
                        notifications GET    /notifications(.:format)                                                                 pages#notifications
                                      POST   /kontakt(.:format)                                                                       emails#create
        rails_postmark_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/postmark/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/postmark/inbound_emails#create
           rails_relay_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails(.:format)                                     action_mailbox/ingresses/relay/inbound_emails#create
        rails_sendgrid_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/sendgrid/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/sendgrid/inbound_emails#create
  rails_mandrill_inbound_health_check GET    /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#health_check
        rails_mandrill_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#create
         rails_mailgun_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mailgun/inbound_emails/mime(.:format)                              action_mailbox/ingresses/mailgun/inbound_emails#create
       rails_conductor_inbound_emails GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#index
                                      POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#create
    new_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/new(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#new
   edit_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id/edit(.:format)                        rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#edit
        rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#show
                                      PATCH  /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                      PUT    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                      DELETE /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#destroy
rails_conductor_inbound_email_reroute POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/reroute(.:format)                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/reroutes#create
                   rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
            rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
                   rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
            update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
                 rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

On my local machine in development mode all works fine. What can I do to fix my problem?

I forgot my nginx setting, here is my sites-available/file:

```
# nginx.conf {appName} == actual name

server {
  listen 443 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 default_server;
  root /var/www/{appName}/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;
  server_name site-preprod.{appName}.de www.site-preprod.{appName}.de;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/{appName}/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/{appName}/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/{appName}/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/{appName}/privkey.pem;



}

server {
    if ($host = www.site-preprod.{appName}.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = site-preprod.{appName}.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


       listen 0.0.0.0:80;
       server_name site-preprod.{appName}.de www.site-preprod.{appName}.de;
       rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent
}
```

Comment: which web server are you using?

Comment: Nginx, with passenger

Comment: It's possible rails isn't receiving the request at all. It might be problem with your NGginx server.

Comment: Hmm, I thought about that too, because the 404 page is loaded by nginx instead of rails.

Comment: This might be caused by missing '/'